# login issue in mysql workbench 6.2.4

Tags: mysql, authentication, mysql-workbench

I have just **installed workbench 6.2.4** version.

When I create a new connection ,

**username : root , 
password : root**

It is not able to make me **login**.

I have attached the image below.

What will be the default username and password when we will do fresh installment of mysql workbench 6.2.4 version ?

Do I need to enter some other details too for login ?
[image]

Comment: Please check the firewall connection and Make sure your MySQL service running

Comment: @ashokhein MySQL service is working, also i have checked firewall.

Comment: If the MySQL service is running then maybe the port settings are not the same, i.e. the server runs on some other port instead of 3306. But I really would double check if the server service is really running. Maybe do the standard thing on Win: reboot the box?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to install MySQL server, which is a separate product. Download the [MySQL Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) for Windows and follow the MySQL server installation process. Also, in the future, use the MySQL Installer to update both MySQL Workbench and MySQL server, and other products, such as MySQL Notifier.